# openUrl in landscape mode in iphone

Tags: iphone, landscape, openurl

I am trying to open the url through safari in landscape mode. But still not able to do it.
Following is the code.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Landscape mode depends on the device orientation. Mobile Safari is a third party (actually Apple's) and you cannot set landscape mode programmatically in an application you did not developed. In fact, even if you set the orientation on your application, as soon as Mobile Safari is launched that setting is lot.